# Position with respect to time electric force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, simulations, coulombs-law

I am working on a simulation where the initial states of the particles are known (charge, acceleration, velocity, and position) and all particles have a constant mass (1). I would like to simulate two particles and thus need a means of calculating position.

My first attempt was to simply use Collumb's law as well as simple kinematics and update the states of the particles with each iteration. This, however, caused an issue of providing estimations and not exact values. As a result when the particles accelerated towards each other, their velocities would grow great enough that in the next iteration they would skip to much further distances away from each other (which is not how these particles should behave).

My next attempt involved simply substituting in Collumbs law for acceleration in the following kinematic:

$$x = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}2 at^2$$
$$x = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}2 cos(\theta) \frac{k_bq_1q_2}{r^2}$$

Although we know $x_0$, $v_0$, $t$, $q_1$, and $q_2$, we don't necessarily know $\theta$ or $r$. Both $r$ and $\theta$ should fluctuate with time, so what should I do? Is it even possible to calculate these positions with nothing but time and initial state? Any tips, equations, or otherwise is very much appreciated. My physics knowledge is only a semesters worth (college level) and so is my calc experience.

Comment: Lots of mistakes here. 1. you need to write dynamcial equations in a general form, and not integrate them by hand; 2. mistakes in the analytical integration; 3. once you solved the other issues, look for a numerical integration scheme that suits the problem. So far, -1

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not experienced in doing simulations, I see a few problems with your approach from the physical point of view.

1. Describing movement of two charged particles is in general not trivial. As charges move, they also produce magnetic field, but changing magnetic field also "produces" electric field. Thus, as soon as the particles start moving, the situation gets more complicated.
2. Your second attempt is unfortunately not proper, because the equation you use is only valid for constant accelerations. Although the particles have constant mass, the force between them changes as they move, and so does the acceleration. Therefore, I wouldn't expect any good solution with such approach.
3. The task you've taken on may be a bit too difficult for you just yet. Knowing that you're currently taking your first semester, I expect that now you're having an introductory mechanics course, and have not yet taken any electromagnetism. Without proper knowledge you may have hard time designing your simulation. Despite that, I think you should not discourage yourself, but if you have time and willingness try to study the topic a bit more. I do not know any worthwhile materials for simulations, but as far as electromagnetism goes, I totally recommend Griffiths' book 'Introduction to Electrodynamics'. Perhaps a good exercise would also be to first try to simulate a single particle moving in an electromagnetic field. For that I'm sure there is a lot of useful materials and examples, e.g., [this repo on Github](https://github.com/niktryf/CParticle).

Good luck with your simulation and remember not to give up!

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your time responding :)